# Recycler view not responding to clicks

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, click

My question is that I want a recycler view to respond to a click on the entire view, not individual clicks on each item that the recycler view has

```
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_amount_reviews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.handleClick()}"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="Title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_event_reviews"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_padding"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.handleClick()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

I want both the title and the recycler view to do the same click function `handleClick` when either of them is clicks. The title `TextView` works but the `RecyclerView` doesn't handle the clicks. How can I accomplish that?

Note: I don't want to wrap both views in one layout since that will add complexity on the entire layout

Comment: if I understood it correctly the android:onClick on recyclerview isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleClick(View view) {
    switch(view) {
        case R.id.tv_amount_reviews:
            //handle textview click;
            break;
        case R.id.rv_event_reviews:
            //handle recycler view click;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a need to  add a switch case since both the views will have the same click function

Comment: why? how fuction can understand what to do if it doesn't know which view call it

Comment: android:onClick will call the  function, and using data binding I can send the view parent who called it, but the problem is not on detecting which view called it

Comment: @Andrea try set for rv_event_reviews this attributes:
android:clickable="true
android:focusable="true"

Comment: @Andrea if you turn off onClick for tv_amount_reviews, is handleClick() executing while you click on rv_event_reviews?

Answer (score 0):

If both views have the same function you can add this to your model

```
public handleClick() {

}
```

You can then add a listener in your model, example

```
private OnClickListener onClickListener = null;

interface OnClickListener{
   void onClick();
}
public handleClick() {
   if(onClickListener != null) onClickListener.onClick();
}

public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener){
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
}
```

If you want to check which view was clicked you would need to change the line below, and then add a view parameter to `handleClick(View v)`

```
@{() -> viewModel.handleClick()} 
to
@{(v) -> viewModel.handleClick(v)} // Don't forget to add a View argument to handleClick
```

Comment: when is setOnClickListener called?

Comment: everytime you click the view, use myModel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener....)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Try to rebuild your project Build-> Rebuild Project

Comment: handleClick needs to have a view as a parameter and it doesn't have one in the code you provided

Comment: if you do this `@{(v) -> viewModel.handleClick(v)} ` yes, otherwise no, you don't need a view as a parameter as i mention on my last paragraph